# How can I tell how long a particular file has been in a directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, samba, timestamp

I want to find (and delete) all files from a directory that have been in the directory longer than X days. I know that I can find files that haven't been modified in an hour with `find /directory/* -mmin 3600`, but when I copy an old file on Windows to my directory on a Debian server, it keeps its age and I can't tell how long it's been there.

Comment: I think this could more easily be done with a file indexing, reading the older-most change to the files or its creation date. sorry i don't provide you a script, but i'm rusty in coding department.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you can even do that, but you might come a little closer by considering the file's *ctime*. That's basically the time of the last change of the metadata, so not quite what you are looking for, but maybe it's close enough?

Comment: if this ( https://launchpad.net/timevault/+download ) can be used with cli scripts it can be done way easier, i think. still i assume one of our experts will come forth with a much more efficient answer.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn There's an idea. Keep relatively frequent snapshots of the directory and check each file against the snapshots. I would definitely be against using the name (if I were in Jakub's position), but that might be acceptable here, or one might be able to compare file content or inode or something. Actually, a full snapshot might not be necessary—one could just periodically walk the directory and hash each of the files, then write all the hashes to a file outside the directory and keep it around to be checked against later.

Comment: And if you used something like `inotify`, you could actually record _exactly_ when a file was added! Hmmm, I think I'm onto something here.

Comment: as i said, someone was probably coming forth with more efficient answers others than snapshotting. and i have read some here already.

Comment: What about simply using `find -cmin`? `ctime` is set whenever a file inode changes, including when a file is moved.

Answer (score 0):

Have a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait --monitor --format="%e %f" --event=create,moved_from,moved_to,delete $directory |
while read event file
do
    case "$event" in
        # asterisks needed because directory events end in ",ISDIR"
        (CREATE*)
            echo "$(date +%s) $file" >>"$index"
            ;;
        (MOVED_TO*)
            # moved_to includes overwrites, so we have to grep out the file, to make sure it wasn't already there
            # use `sponge` to enable safe reading and writing of the index in the same pipeline
            grep -Fv " $file" "$index" | sponge "$index"
            echo "$(date +%s) $file" >>"$index"
            ;;
        (MOVED_FROM*|DELETE*)
            grep -Fv " $file" "$index" | sponge "$index"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

File accesses and modifications are ignored and do not change the index; however, if you rename a file, its timestamp will be updated.

There's never any need to `sort` the index; we only ever append new files to the end of the index and remove them from the middle.

`inotifywait`, as invoked in the script, listens for file events, and outputs the event type, a space, the name of the file or directory that caused the event, and a newline. You may replace it with an equivalent program.

`sponge` simply reads all input from `stdin` into an internal buffer, then writes it out to a file. You may replace it with an equivalent, or, alternately, write output to `${index}.new` and then `mv -f "${index}.new" "$index"`.

`date +%s` outputs the current date and time as number of seconds from the Epoch. This invocation works with both GNU and BSD `date`s. You may change the format (e.g. `date '+%F %T'`) for a human-readable index or replace `date` with an equivalent.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell. You may replace it with an equivalent. :)

Answer (score -1):

This should work, eg 10 hours ago:

```
X=10; find /directory/ -type f -atime $X -exec echo rm -fv {} ';'
```

-atime is "last accessed n*24 hours ago", remove "echo" if it does what you want.

also for files last modifed an hour ago, this is simpler:

```
find . -mtime 1
```